# Copper or Brass for G-Clamp busbar

Tags: copper, busbar, gclamp, brass

I'm looking into a busbar for a test setup temporarily wire up G-Clamps.
The test setup will then perform electrical tests (for the cable) or high current and voltage. (100A for seconds)

Existing test busbar is made of copper and quickly is mangled and damaged because copper is soft, plus it reacts with air and fingerprints. Making it an expensive consumable.

As an alternative Brass came up. This can also conduct well, is harder and does not react to air as aggressive.
However I am unsure of the capabilities of brass as electrical connection surface for these kind of currents.

Would this be feasible? Or would it be worth it to look into copper platings?

Comment: Brass is about 15-30% the conductivity of copper. Copper plating is too thin to really matter and would just oxidize away. There's also aluminum. Electrical grade aluminum might not be harder (I am unsure) but it will be cheaper.